# Австриец или австрияк?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Жителей Австрии называют то австрийцами, то австрияками (аналогично пруссаки). А как все-таки правильно?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Можно  ещё  спросить  как  правильно - японец  или  япошка ?  Из  той  же  оперы !

Comment: Если вопрос о Курильских островах, то нечего миндальничать: япошки!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: австриец (нейтральный стиль). У Ушакова: АВСТРИЯК - это  австриец (с оттенком некоторого презрения).